# Central pool of Android Virtual Devices for running tests

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, android-gradle-plugin

To speed up our Jenkins CI pipeline, we are looking for a solution to the long times needed to start a new Android Virtual Device.
We figured it would be nice to have a centralized in-house server, running several virtual devices (different Android versions for instance) that can be used for running tests.
That way we no longer have to start an AVD and we can reuse these resources for multiple projects.

I know that several companies offer cloud instances for this (Manymo for example) and some of them even offer nice integration with the Gradle build automation tool we are using, but we would really like to run something on our own servers.

Does anyone know of an existing tool that can do such a thing?

PS: I did some experimenting over the weekend and I did figure out some ways to achieve such a system, but I would rather not reinvent the wheel, if the "wheel" in this case has already been created.

Comment: Looking for a solution for this as well.

Comment: I recently started with the creation of such a service in my sparetime. Hopefully I can post some results online soon!

Comment: Still a work in progress, but my tests so far (while creating a full proof of concept) are promising.